# How to get disabled privileges for access token?

Tags: c++, winapi

I know that an access token has disabled and enabled privileges. With some rights, I can enable privileges which are disabled, but I can't get how to receive a list of them. If I use the `PrivilegeCheck()` function, it just returns me the enabled privileges.

Can you give me a hint as to how to get a list of disabled privileges (may be a code snippet, function, or another direction)?

I use this code:

```
// Get Process Handle with QUERY_INFORMATION rights
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, PID);
// Get Access Token with READ rights
OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE, &hToken);
// Get ID of privelege in the system
if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, priv_list[i], &luid))  continue;
// Set checking privilege by one 
privs.PrivilegeCount = 1;
privs.Control = PRIVILEGE_SET_ALL_NECESSARY;
privs.Privilege[0].Luid = luid;
privs.Privilege[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
// Check enabled privilege
PrivilegeCheck(hToken, &privs, &bResult);
```

It just returns the enabled privileges, not the disabled ones.

I repeat again, if the process has disabled privileges that I can activate, I want to list them.

In the end, I want to get something like this:

[image: Process Hacker Privileges]

Comment: `GetTokenInformation` with `TokenPrivileges` return `TOKEN_PRIVILEGES` structure . in `LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES` look `Attributes` - are containing `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED`

Comment: I *though* privileges are constants. So every one out of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/privilege-constants) that is not enabled/held, is disabled. Might be wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RbMm said, **traversing permissions** is a method.

1. Get the token handle and query the permissions of the token.
2. `GetTokenInformation()`.
3. Return TOKEN_PRIVILEGES struct.

Here is a sample, hope this helpful.

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
                HANDLE hToken = NULL;
                OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);
                if (!hToken)
                {
                                printf("OpenProcessToken() error\n");
                                return 0;
                }

                DWORD dwSize = 0;
                GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, NULL, NULL, &dwSize);

                TOKEN_PRIVILEGES* pTokenPriv = (TOKEN_PRIVILEGES*)calloc(1, dwSize);
                GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, pTokenPriv, dwSize, &dwSize);

                DWORD dwCount = pTokenPriv->PrivilegeCount;
                LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES* pPriv = pTokenPriv->Privileges;
                
                char szPrivName[1000] = { 0 };

                DWORD dwNameLen = sizeof(szPrivName);
                for (int i = 0; i < dwCount; ++i)
                {
                                
                                LookupPrivilegeNameA(0, &(pPriv[i].Luid), szPrivName, &dwNameLen);
                                printf("[%s] -- Attributes:[%d]\n", szPrivName, pPriv[i].Attributes);
                }

                if (pTokenPriv)
                {
                                free(pTokenPriv);
                                pTokenPriv = NULL;
                }
}
```